# convert radio buttons into stars

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have some radio buttons that I'm trying to convert into stars and I'm following these example to create a star-rating component: https://codepen.io/muhammad_mabrouk/pen/bWybwX

I am still learning react, so I do not know how to import bootstrap in this component. What I need to import is:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Here is the code:

```js
import { Component } from 'react'
import React from 'react';
import PageTemplate from './PageTemplate'
import '../css/starRating.css';

class Rating extends Component {

    render(){
        return (
          <div>
            <input id="star-5" type="radio" name="rating" value="star-5"></input>
            <label for="star-5" title="5 stars">
                <i class="active fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </label>
            <input id="star-4" type="radio" name="rating" value="star-4"></input>
            <label for="star-4" title="4 stars">
                <i class="active fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </label>
            <input id="star-3" type="radio" name="rating" value="star-3"></input>
            <label for="star-3" title="3 stars">
                <i class="active fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </label>
            <input id="star-2" type="radio" name="rating" value="star-2"></input>
            <label for="star-2" title="2 stars">
                <i class="active fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </label>
            <input id="star-1" type="radio" name="rating" value="star-1"></input>
            <label for="star-1" title="1 star">
                <i class="active fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </label>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Rating;
```

I will appreciate all your help.

Comment: did you try https://react-bootstrap.github.io/introduction.html??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

inside `public` folder , `index.html` file.

---

OR

Download that file and store it locally, then place it with your `starRating.css`

Then import same as `starRating.css`

```
import '../css/starRating.css';
import '../css/font-awesome.min.css';
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand when you say "place it with your starRating.css", I apply your second option and I received this error: ./src/css/font-awesome.min.css
Module not found: Can't resolve '../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0'

Comment: @Jenn, Okay if you want to follow the second option you need to download all other font files also, I would suggest you follow the first step that will be easy. :)

Comment: okay, so I just placed it in the html file but the radio buttons still look the same, do I have to "call it" somewhere in my Rating component? and how? :(

Comment: No, that's enough , you can check it by view page source , I think it will some other issue.